# How to replace the string in textbox when keyboard tab is pressed in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, typescript, replace

in this text box when the user wants to type any name it should be converted to a specific pattern for example if the user types `Text@1` in the console, I want to print `$[Text@1]`but not`Text@1$[Text@1]` ,by clicking the keyboard tab button, I have tried `e.keyCode===9` and `[\t]` by giving a condition but it is still not working, so how can I solve this issue?

```
import { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
    e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(
      /[^A-Za-z0-9-\s!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/g,
      `$[${value}]`
    );
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        value={value}
        onKeyPress={(e) => {
          if (e.target.value.length >= 15) e.preventDefault();
        }}
        placeholder="type value"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using controlled way to manage your input so that your input tag refers the state `value` but your event handler set the value before mutate it.

###### code sample

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target
    const regex = /[^A-Za-z0-9-\s!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/g
    const newValue = value.replace(regex, `$[${value}]`)
    setValue(newValue);
    console.log({ value, newValue })
  };
```

Comment: But when you are clicking the keyboard tab after giving any input, it's not working.

Comment: If u r talking about triggering event by tab, "e.keyCode===9" can be implemented in onKeyPress not on change handler